# what is the hibernate tools plugin for eclipse update site url?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

Or perhaps this is a manual install only deal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crap - it's http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable